# How to type hint an element or list of Literals in Python?

Tags: python, type-hinting

Suppose I have a variable x and a list of values ['a', 'b', 'c']. x can be just 'a' or 'b' or 'c' or a list of these values like ['a', 'b'] or ['a', 'c', 'a'] and so on. How do I write type hint for x in Python?

Comment: do you meant `typing.Union[typing.Literal["a","b","c"], list[typing.Literal["a","b","c"]]]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [Union](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union):

> Union type; Union[X, Y] is equivalent to X | Y and means either X or Y.

Example:

```py
from typing import List
from typing import Union

def func(arg: bool) -> Union[str, List[str]]:    
    if arg:
        x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    else:
        x = 'c'

    return x


print(type(func(True))) # <class 'list'>
print(type(func(False))) # <class 'str'>
```